# Fallan las opciones de reescritura de la url. Envío POST de Angular a PHP/Servidor

Tags: php, angular, servidor, .htaccess, rewriterule

Experimento un problema que solamente me pasa en mi nuevo servidor de Arsys.

Estoy haciendo un **login Angular/PHP** que siempre me ha funcionado, pero ahora no.

He revisado cabeceras *Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-type: application/json, etc* y no parece ser el problema, dado que en **LOCALHOST** todo funciona perfecto.

Desde Angular **envío con POST** el formulario que me llega a PHP con:

```
 $postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

Hago la consulta y doy salida con

```
 echo json_encode($arrayRB1);
```

Insisto, ***en entorno local me funciona perfecto***, sin embargo al subirlo a mi servidor Arsys y haciendo pruebas con POSTMAN, me devuelve *status 200* pero no me muestra nada en la salida, cosa que sí hace en localhost:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El servicio técnico de Arsys me dice que lo que le está fallando son **las opciones de reescritura de la url**. Me recomiendan que utilice un fichero **.htaccess** modificando estas opciones.

He usado un .htaccess en el directorio raíz del FTP con solamente ***"RewriteEngine on"***, pero no obtengo solución.

Alguna sugerencia sobre qué opciones debería modificar y dónde alojar el .htaccess??

Comment: Esto mismo pasa en GoDaddy y su respuesta fue que el modo Rewrite solo se activa pagando, quizas debes contactarte con el soporte para ver como te ayuda ya que lo desactivan por "seguridad"

Comment: @ernesto jimenez en este caso ignoro si es de pago, pero el tio del servicio técnico me ha dicho que o solucione así, por lo que deduzco que quizá no sea ese el caso

Comment: Pues tengo entendido que el modo rewrite solo se activa desde el php.ini pero directamente desde los archivos principales